# Compiling haru text_demo.c error

Tags: pdf, compiler-errors

Downloaded and installed 2.2.1 on Redhat Linux and tried to compile text_demo.c, but it complains about missing grid_sheet.h.  So I downloaded 2.0.8 to get grid_sheet.h.  Now when I try to compile I get these errors:

> gcc -o text_demo -I /usr/local/include I
>   /home/downloads/libharu-2.0.8/demo -L /usr/local/lib text_demo.c
>
> /tmp/ccmPxCcu.o: In function `show_stripe_pattern':
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_Page_SetRGBStroke' text_demo.c:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference
>   to `HPDF_Page_SetLineWidth' text_demo.c:(.text+0xa6): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_MoveTo' text_demo.c:(.text+0xd0): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_TextWidth' text_demo.c:(.text+0xe9): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_LineTo' text_demo.c:(.text+0xf4): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_Stroke' text_demo.c:(.text+0x116): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_SetLineWidth' /tmp/ccmPxCcu.o: In function
>   `show_description': text_demo.c:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_Page_GetCurrentFontSize' text_demo.c:(.text+0x137): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_GetCurrentFont' text_demo.c:(.text+0x14c):
>   undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_GetRGBFill'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x15a): undefined reference to
>   `HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x180): undefined reference
>   to`HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill' text_demo.c:(.text+0x193): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_SetTextRenderingMode'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x1ae): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize' text_demo.c:(.text+0x1d6): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_TextOut' text_demo.c:(.text+0x1e1): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_EndText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x1fa): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize' text_demo.c:(.text+0x21a):
>   undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill' /tmp/ccmPxCcu.o: In
>   function `main': text_demo.c:(.text+0x2ab): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_New' text_demo.c:(.text+0x2ea): undefined reference to
>   `HPDF_Free' text_demo.c:(.text+0x30c): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_SetCompressionMode' text_demo.c:(.text+0x327): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_GetFont' text_demo.c:(.text+0x335): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_AddPage' text_demo.c:(.text+0x34a): undefined
>   reference to `print_grid' text_demo.c:(.text+0x365): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize' text_demo.c:(.text+0x377):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_TextWidth'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x385): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x390): undefined reference
>   to `HPDF_Page_GetHeight' text_demo.c:(.text+0x3a9): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_GetWidth' text_demo.c:(.text+0x3d4): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_TextOut' text_demo.c:(.text+0x3df): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_EndText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x3ea): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x3f5):
>   undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_GetHeight'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x415): undefined reference to
>   `HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos' text_demo.c:(.text+0x43b): undefined reference
>   to`HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize' text_demo.c:(.text+0x45c): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos' text_demo.c:(.text+0x47c):
>   undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_GetWidth' text_demo.c:(.text+0x4aa):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_MeasureText'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x4cd): undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_ShowText'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x4ea): undefined reference to
>   `HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos' text_demo.c:(.text+0x505): undefined reference
>   to`HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize' text_demo.c:(.text+0x53f): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_ShowText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x57c): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize' text_demo.c:(.text+0x599):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x5ac): undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_ShowText'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x5c7): undefined reference to
>   `HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize' text_demo.c:(.text+0x5e4): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos' text_demo.c:(.text+0x665):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x67a): undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_ShowText'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x6a3): undefined reference to
>   `HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos' text_demo.c:(.text+0x6fe): undefined reference
>   to`HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill' text_demo.c:(.text+0x713): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_ShowText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x73c): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos' text_demo.c:(.text+0x797):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x7ac): undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_ShowText'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x7c3): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_EndText'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x7e6): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize' text_demo.c:(.text+0x80c): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill' text_demo.c:(.text+0x820):
>   undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_SetLineWidth'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x856): undefined reference to
>   `HPDF_Page_SetTextRenderingMode' text_demo.c:(.text+0x861): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x884):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_TextOut' text_demo.c:(.text+0x88f):
>   undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_EndText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x8cd):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetTextRenderingMode'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x8d8): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x903): undefined reference
>   to `HPDF_Page_TextOut' text_demo.c:(.text+0x90e): undefined reference
>   to`HPDF_Page_EndText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x94c): undefined reference
>   to `HPDF_Page_SetTextRenderingMode' text_demo.c:(.text+0x957):
>   undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_BeginText'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x982): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_TextOut'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x98d): undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_EndText'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x9c3): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_GSave'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x9d6): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_Page_SetTextRenderingMode' text_demo.c:(.text+0x9e1): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xa0c):
>   undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_TextOut' text_demo.c:(.text+0xa17):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_EndText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xa45):
>   undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_GRestore' text_demo.c:(.text+0xa7b):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_GSave' text_demo.c:(.text+0xa8e):
>   undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_SetTextRenderingMode'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0xa99): undefined reference to
>   `HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xac4): undefined reference
>   to`HPDF_Page_TextOut' text_demo.c:(.text+0xacf): undefined reference
>   to `HPDF_Page_EndText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xafd): undefined reference
>   to`HPDF_Page_GRestore' text_demo.c:(.text+0xb33): undefined reference
>   to `HPDF_Page_GSave' text_demo.c:(.text+0xb46): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_Page_SetTextRenderingMode' text_demo.c:(.text+0xb51): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xb7c):
>   undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_TextOut' text_demo.c:(.text+0xb87):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_EndText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xbb5):
>   undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_GRestore' text_demo.c:(.text+0xbc8):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetTextRenderingMode'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0xbee): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill' text_demo.c:(.text+0xc09): undefined reference
>   to `HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize' text_demo.c:(.text+0xc5d): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xc79):
>   undefined reference to `cos' text_demo.c:(.text+0xc8a): undefined
>   reference to`sin' text_demo.c:(.text+0xcb3): undefined reference to
>   `sin' text_demo.c:(.text+0xcc4): undefined reference to`cos'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0xd0a): undefined reference to
>   `HPDF_Page_SetTextMatrix' text_demo.c:(.text+0xd1d): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_ShowText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xd28): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_EndText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xd5e): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xdb6):
>   undefined reference to `tan' text_demo.c:(.text+0xdc7): undefined
>   reference to`tan' text_demo.c:(.text+0xe11): undefined reference to
>   `HPDF_Page_SetTextMatrix' text_demo.c:(.text+0xe24): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_ShowText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xe2f): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_EndText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xe65): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xeac):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetTextMatrix'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0xebf): undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_ShowText'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0xeca): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_EndText'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0xf00): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xf47): undefined reference
>   to `HPDF_Page_SetTextMatrix' text_demo.c:(.text+0xf5a): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_ShowText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xf65): undefined
>   reference to `HPDF_Page_EndText' text_demo.c:(.text+0xfef): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize' text_demo.c:(.text+0x1015):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x1020): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x1044): undefined reference
>   to `HPDF_Page_TextOut' text_demo.c:(.text+0x104f): undefined reference
>   to`HPDF_Page_EndText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x1063): undefined reference
>   to `HPDF_Page_SetCharSpace' text_demo.c:(.text+0x106e): undefined
>   reference to`HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x1092):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_TextOut' text_demo.c:(.text+0x109d):
>   undefined reference to`HPDF_Page_EndText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x10b1):
>   undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetWordSpace'
>   text_demo.c:(.text+0x10bc): undefined reference to`
>   HPDF_Page_BeginText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x10e0): undefined reference
>   to `HPDF_Page_TextOut' text_demo.c:(.text+0x10eb): undefined reference
>   to`HPDF_Page_EndText' text_demo.c:(.text+0x1100): undefined reference
>   to `HPDF_SaveToFile' text_demo.c:(.text+0x110b): undefined reference
>   to`HPDF_Free' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 2):

All libharu functions are missing because the library was not found. Please change your -L option.